# Django doesn't recognize my custom update method in a serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i'm trying to patch an object in an app in Django Rest Framework

But im getting the following error

AssertionError at /requirements/material/12/
The `.update()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `requirement.serializers.MaterialRequirementDetailSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.

The main problem here is that i already create an explicit update method.

Here is my View.py where i make the patch request

```
def patch(self, request, pk, format=None): 
        requirement = models.MaterialRequirement.objects.get(pk=pk)

        serializer = serializers.MaterialRequirementDetailSerializer(
            requirement,
            data = request.data,
            partial = True
        )
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

and here is the serializer that i'm using

```
class MaterialRequirementDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    
    owner = UserListSerializer()
    construction_site = ConstructionSiteListSerializer()
    quotations = QuotationListSerializer(
        source='quotation_set',
        many=True,
        read_only=True
    )
    items = RequirementItemSerializer(
        many=True

    )
    state = serializers.CharField(source='get_state_display')
    type = serializers.CharField(source='get_type_display')
    delivery_time = serializers.CharField(source= 'get_delivery_time_display')

    class Meta:
        model = MaterialRequirement
        fields = (
            'id',
            'code',
            'state',
            'type',
            'deadline',
            'description',
            'observation',
            'owner',
            'construction_site',
            'delivery_date',
            'delivery_time',
            'quotations',
            'items'
        )
    
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        requirement = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        items = self.context.get('items', None)
        if items:
            for item in items:
                if 'id' in item.keys():
                    requirement_item = RequirementItem.objects.get(pk=item['id'])
                    if requirement_item:
                        requirement_item.name = item['name']
                        requirement_item.description = item['description']
                        requirement_item.is_urgent = item['is_urgent']
                        requirement_item.quantity = item['quantity']
                        requirement_item.save()
                else:
                    RequirementItem.objects.create(requirement = requirement, **item)
        requirement.save()
        return requirement
```

Comment: calling the ***`super()`*** method casing the issue, -> `super().update(instance, validated_data)`

Comment: Have you looked at [`drf-writable-nested`](https://pypi.org/project/drf-writable-nested/) ?

Comment: Indeed the `super()` method is causing the issue but i cannot understand why,  @ArakkalAbu

Comment: The bare `update(...)` method expects the data in *X* format whereas you are passing the data in *Y* format. The idea of overriding the `update()` method is that, either convert the *Y* to *X* and call the `super()` method or *"perform an update operation "somehow"* with *X*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you use `super().update` with the fields that are nested. You should take them out of validated_data. And use set them after `super().update`.

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    field = validated_data.pop("field")
    requirement = super().update(instance, validated_data)
    ...
    requirement.save()
    return requirement
```